# How to change Nvidia graphic resolution in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: nvidia, resolution

I ran this command in the terminal:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

After that the only resolution that I have is 640*480! My screen's resolution is 1366*768 in windows. How can I set the resolution to 1366*768??

Comment: what video card are you using?

Comment: my graphic card is Nvidia GT540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simply want to change resolution manually go to `system settings/displays` and apply desired one.

if you got messed up with nvidia configuration do the following:

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start
```

if you need to configure new installation of nvidia run in terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig

gksudo nvidia-settings
```